# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de la fila al seleccionar un checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, checkbox

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con **datatable** y **datatables.checkboxes** para que me incluya un **checkbox** a mi tabla tanto al `<thead>` como al `<tbody>`.

Lo que quiero saber es como obtener los valores de los campos de la fila por el checkbox que se seleccionó para luego al dar `clic` a mi boton ***Obtener*** me devuelva un json con las filas seleccionadas.

En el código mostrado líneas abajo he podido obtener el valor de todas las filas al dar clic a mi ***boton*** pero lo que yo quiero es obtener el valor de solo lo que esten con el ***checkbox*** seleccionado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    MantCostos.crear_tabla_Excel();
    MantCostos.ObtenerDatosSeleccionados();
});

var MantCostos = (function() {
 return {
  crear_tabla_Excel: function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
    columnDefs: [
     {
      targets: 0,
      checkboxes: {
       selectRow: true,
      },
     },
    ],
    select: {
     style: 'multi',
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
   });
        },
        ObtenerDatosSeleccionados:function(){
            $("#btnObtener").click(function(){
                var tabla = $("#example").DataTable();
                var datos = tabla.data().toArray();
                console.log(datos);
            });
        }
 };
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
        </tfoot>
     </table>

     <button type="button" id="btnObtener">Obtener</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta buscando todos los checkbox que esten seleccionados, luego buscas los tr mas cercanos a ese checkbox que seran los tr padres y una vez obtenido los `tr`, puedes obtener la data de cada uno de los `tr` utilizando la API  [`DataTable.row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    MantCostos.crear_tabla_Excel();
    MantCostos.ObtenerDatosSeleccionados();
});

var MantCostos = (function() {
 return {
  crear_tabla_Excel: function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
    columnDefs: [
     {
      targets: 0,
      checkboxes: {
       selectRow: true,
      },
     },
    ],
    select: {
     style: 'multi',
    },
    order: [[1, 'asc']],
   });
        },
        ObtenerDatosSeleccionados:function(){
            $("#btnObtener").click(function(){
                var tabla = $("#example").DataTable();
                var data = [];
                $("#example tbody .dt-checkboxes:checked") // buscamos los checkbox seleccionados dentro del tbody de la tabla
                .each((index, element)=>{ 
                    // por cada checkbox, buscamos la data del tr padre utilizando row(htmlElemento).data();
                    data.push( tabla.row( $(element).closest("tr")[0]).data() );
                });

                console.log(data);
            });
        }
 };
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css">
     <button type="button" id="btnObtener">Obtener</button>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Extn.</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
           </tr>
        </tfoot>
     </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
```